# Generate a square waveform in C?

Tags: c, waveform

How to generate an efficient square waveform with varying duty cycle using C language?

Comment: What's the desired output? (audio tone? graphic? some other file?)

Comment: desired o/p is to display a square waveform on you window wrt varying duty cycle... its a pwm o/p which I'm expecting...

Comment: o/p being output, but what's pwm?

Answer (score 1):

Choose your output format.  Headerless PCM is probably best to start with.  Select your output format - say, 16 bit stereo at 44 KHz.  Choose your endianness.  Write a bit of code which emits to a file logical 0 for 1 seconds worth of data; then emits logical 65535 for one second worth of data.  Repeat.

That file contains your waveform.

Comment: Or do you mean a video waveform?

Comment: That doesn't sound as if it addresses the "varying duty cycle" requirement, though.

Comment: Well, the '1 seconds worth of data' repeated is the duty cycle.  The good news is the audio will compress rather well.

Comment: Does he rather mean that it should output this Live(straight to the sound card) and in a multitasking environment? Cause that would be a much less trivial question

Answer (score 1):

Let N be the cycle length (1 / frequency). N is a count of some small quanta, like clock ticks. Let D be the amount of quanta the output is high during each cycle of N. The algorithm is trivial:

```
loop indefinitely:
  for D ticks:
    output 1
  for N - D ticks:
    output 0
```